# Limit ports to specific subdomains

Tags: email, windows-server-2008-r2, email-server, port-forwarding

When using a professional webhotel hosting company, their serveraddress to the incoming e-mails (pop3 / imap) are limited to a specific subdomain.

```
Example: Port 25 (SMTP) can only be accessed via smtp.domain.com
         Port 143 (IMAP) can only be accessed via mail.domain.com
```

How to configure this on my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine? Is it through the firewall, or?

Comment: If those are _external_ machines, by firewall. If those are alternate names (via DNS), no way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think they just have different servers for their website (www.domain.com) and mail-servers (mail.domain.com / smtp.domain.com) with corresponding dns-records.
in this case, you can only access port 25/143 via smtp.domain.com / mail.domain.com because there is a mailserver waiting for connections on this ports...